# Keep getting Completed 500 internal server error heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When deploy my rails app to heroku and do all my migrates, I can create new admin with no problem, but when i go to create a user, i type all my information in, click create and get

"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

with the log listing below showing i got a 500 internal server error and I am not sure why, considering it worked recently and all of a sudden it stopped and now nothing i do makes it work properly.

Any help would be amazing.

Below is my heroku logs and it is near the bottom where the error occurs

```
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/schem
a.rb:17:in `dump_table'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/bin/schema:32:
in `<main>'
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:07
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:36:in `require': LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Sequel:
:AdapterNotFound)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
bygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
bygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
bygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `block in tsk_require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/se
quel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/schem
a.rb:39:in `indexes_individual'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/bin/schema:36:
in `<main>'
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       unexpected nil (OkJson::ParserError)
    Backtrace:   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/vendor
/okjson.rb:82:in `valparse'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/vendor
/okjson.rb:64:in `textparse'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/vendor
/okjson.rb:43:in `decode'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/o
peration.rb:419:in `push_indexes'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/o
peration.rb:408:in `block in run'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/o
peration.rb:203:in `call'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/o
peration.rb:203:in `catch_errors'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/o
peration.rb:405:in `run'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/c
li.rb:171:in `clientxfer'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:192:in `t
aps_client'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:30:in `pu
sh'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'

                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku db:push
    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/2.35.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3


C:\Users\Kibo\rubyProj\group9-backend>heroku logs
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_retu
rning_status'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:19
2:in `transaction'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/admin/users h
ost=radiant-lake-1769.herokuapp.com fwd="174.91.15.111" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2
ms connect=11ms service=3134ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_sta
tus'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/tran
sactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in save_res
ource'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:27:in `save_resource'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:22:in `block in create_r
esource'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:78:in `run_save_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:78:in `run_create_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:21:in `create_resource'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/inherited_r
esources-1.3.1/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:33:in `create'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin
-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:48:in `create'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__1109873420186423599__proc
ess_action__1269607343105267632__callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_act
ion'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0
.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0
.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.
1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0
.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.
1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.
1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecor
d-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in
 `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__381718374095792030__call_
_4177206034446482028__callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-
3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesuppo
rt-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-
1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-
1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.
rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-
1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-
1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-
1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpser
ver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Admin::UsersController#create
 as HTML
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "authenticity
_token"=>"8idZkNz66cMpb85HVIgVQhtwGj8fZnHphVE2fBRCjXU=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Bojan"
, "email"=>"bdjordje@ryerson.ca", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmatio
n"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/de
vise-2.2.3/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.4ms)
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/
lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3119
ms
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.
2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-23T21:09:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpser
ver.rb:70:in `run'

C:\Users\Kibo\rubyProj\group9-backend>
```

Comment: I am using devise btw

Comment: C'mon... a little bit of formatting the logs would be great. Put them in a pastebin/gist.

Comment: Did you get this error when you were building your app locally in development?

Comment: when i did it locally i had no errors and worked fine when i ran rails server. There i can do everything, just when i upload it to heroku it seems to get that error. I can create a new admin on heroku without a problem, but the user fails. I think the problem is with the database, maybe migrating it to heroku, but i tried to reset it and that was not working either

Comment: did you run your migrations?

Comment: yes, i rand db:dorp db:create and db:migrate locally before uploading. After i pushed to heroku, i did heroku pg:reset, heroku run rake db:migrate and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. I had to comment out all the confirmable attributes in user.rb in both the admin folder where the table is created and the model which defines the attributes, as well as in the migration file since it was trying to send an email to the user upon creation. Once i did this, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
_require.rb:36:inrequire': LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Sequel: :AdapterNotFound) from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
```

Did you change your gem file to

```
gem 'pg'
```

?

Comment: i did, my gem file is setup as follows:

group :production do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end

Comment: i even tried heroku pg:restart, and then migrating my database again, but still same result. I didn't really change much, just my user.rb to add a column, as well as the migration for the user, and i did run rake to get the new schema before pushing it on heroku.

Comment: try removing complele the sqlite from the gem file, and try again, and copy the log after

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Bojan011/c08c928c761f9baea2ef

you can check the new log there with the sqlite removed from gemfile

Answer (score 0):

```
 Command:     heroku db:push
```

Don't use `db:push` or `db:pull`. Use `pgbackups` to import/export data: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export